# Connecting Eclipse project to new GitHub repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have been coding up a new project for several weeks and finally decided to put it up on GitHub. So I installed Git (`sudo apt-get install git`), created an account on GitHub, and then created a new repository with the same name as my Eclipse project. I'm now trying to add my existing Eclipse project to Git version control, and connect it to my GitHub repository.

I ran `git init /home/myuser/sandbox/workspace/MyApp`.

How do I now connect it to my HitHub repo, so that when I `git push` some changes, I'll be able to login to GitHub and see them?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest (and probably the best) method to install [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin, and then either import from local repository or from github

[image]

If you already have eclipse project you can just 'right click' on it and 'share'.
After select provider (git) just add your github repo url and have fun.

Comment: Thanks @mishadoff (+1) - does installing egit also install `git` or do I have to first install `git`? Thanks again!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys EGit plugin installs own implementation of git, so, basically, you don't need install git manually. I recommend to have not eclipse dependent git provider, though.